# A bean with RestController, Component and Configuration annotations simultaneously violates the SRP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, solid-principles

In a Java Spring application I came into the following situation:

```
import ...

@Component
@RestController
@Configuration
public class MySender { ... }
```

At first sight I tought that this certainly violates the Single Responsibility Principle, and that it isn't a good practice. The context of this code is a class that calls a @Scheduled method to send messages to a queue, it doesn't even have a HTTP method. The fact that this was approved in code reviews and it had been presented to me by a senior dev made me had doubts about my understanding of the code, I searched and didn't find anything related to the combined use of this annotations.

Comment: If it isn't related to the web `@RestController` doesn't make sense, if it doesn't provide configuration the `@Cofiguration` doesn't make sense. If it is then the `@Component` doesn't make sense.

Comment: A `@RestController` is a `@Component` so at the very least there is redundancy in mentioning both.